# How to define a large list array in Python using For loop or Vectorization?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D list of 416 rows, each row having 4 columns.  Rows 1-4 contain their row number 4 times (i.e., `[...[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2]...]`.  Row 330 contains `[41,22,13,13]`.  Everything else is `[0,0,0,0]`.  Currently I am using a for loop with many explicit if statements.

```
myList = [[0,0,0,0]]
for i in range(1, 416):
    if i == 1 or i == 2 or i == 3 or i == 4:
        myList.append([i,i,i,i])
    elif i == 330:
        myList.append([41,22,13,13])
    else:
        myList.append([0,0,0,0])
```

What is a more efficient way for me to define this array?

The other questions I have seen on SO don't seem to explicitly address this question, but if someone finds one that can be considered a duplicate please mark this question as such and I will accept it.

Comment: does this have to be a `list` or are other formats ok?

Comment: I'd prefer list.  But!  The main thing I care about is the end result, so if you know of another, better method, lay it on me.

Comment: Have you looked at numpy arrays? Much like @Moses's answer, I'd start with a np.zeros and then adjust the necessary rows.

Comment: I do know (and love) numpy, but I have encountered more than one instance where I have a task or assignment that does not permit the use of numpy.  In addition, I am a big fan of improving one's use of the simpler tools before going to more advanced ones.  So I suppose their is a CS Theory aspect to this question as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the bulk of the list is a sublist of zeros (in array term, sparse), I'll just preallocate and then use slice assignment/indexing to update:

```
my_list = [[0, 0, 0, 0] for _ in range(416)]
my_list[330] = [41,22,13,13]
my_list[1:5] = [[i]*4 for i in range(1, 5)]
```

This avoids repeated branch evaluation for a host of false cases and the repeated appends.

OTOH, having zeros all over your memory can be avoided if you actually keep the data structure as a sparse matrix. You could have a look at the [SciPy 2-D sparse matrix package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Comment: Surely the right idea, but the output from their code snippet is not equal to this output (their output may be wrong)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'll say their output is wrong. They are pre-assigning `myList = [[]]`.

Comment: If `my_list` is not going to be modified, you can even say `zero_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]` and then start with `my_list = [zero_list for _ in range(416)]`, saving the time and memory used in creating unnecessary lists.

Comment: @jdehesa Not a good idea. You do a reference copy there, mutating every list just by changing 1.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, I fixed it.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye, if you replace `[[0, 0, 0, 0] for _ in range(416)]` with `[[0, 0, 0, 0]]*416` it would be 2 time faster!

Comment: @CommonSense ikr, that duplicates your sublist across the list and all hell unleashes. It's a bad idea. See what happens when you update one of the sublists.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That's why I said "if `my_list` is not going to be modified" (I meant `my_list` and its elements); although I guess in that case you might as well use tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, a really simple and fast way to do it:

```
import itertools

answer = list(itertools.chain([[i,i,i,i] for i in range(1,5)], [[0,0,0,0] for _ in range(330-6)], [[41,22,13,13]], [[0,0,0,0] for _ in range(416-330)]))
```